# Hide File on localhost of XAMPP server

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I have created a project in PHP and placed it inside htdocs in XAMPP server.
I want to give the project to my friend to run that project locally on his machine to test it .

I don't want him to access the folders and directories I just want him to use the project what is shown in the browser. I want neither he can see my code nor access the files locally.He just can test the functionality in the project.

Is there any way or any tool to do that. Thanks

I use a third-party tool to lock that folder then I cannot access the file from the browser?.

thanks

Comment: well, you must have a foundation to know, that php is using interpreter, it's open source for any user on that PC/NB and in my opinion just activate your ip become public, please take a look in htaccess apache configuration.

Comment: You could obfuscate the source. It won't prevent reverse engineering however. It will make an uninterested person not bother. Option 2, you could clone the rendered results (browser level), and give him that. Option 3, you could fire him now since you dont trust him.

Comment: This makes no sense, this is not how the platform of a web application works. Instead you should publish your application using a http server you yourself control. So that your "friend" (I guess that reads your paying customer?) can access the server only via http protocol, so the way you want things to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) and serve the app from your local host to the internet. You control when it's available, nobody can access the source code and you don't need a real domain or subdomain to do it.

Comment: I can not do that but the requirement is that I need to transfer the code to his machine and ask him to check all the changes locally I just can't access the internet

Comment: Well then, I'm afraid you cannot do that without transferring the full source code. Even if it's not accessible from XAMPP itself (Apache to be more accurate), nothing would stop him to just open the folder and have a look at the files.